# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 182704

Tags: vue.js, npm, github-actions

I am building a Vue Application, when running npm run build in GitHub Actions workflow, the following error occurred:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 182704
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /home/runner/work/IS212-g4t1/IS212-g4t1/frontend/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:144:30
    at Socket.onChunk (/home/runner/work/IS212-g4t1/IS212-g4t1/frontend/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/readBuffer.js:40:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

Node.js v18.18.0
npm verb exit 1
npm verb code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

However, when I run npm run build locally and deploy the Vue app to vercel (also runs npm run build), it does not give an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Azure DevOps yesterday. It seems to be caused by an updated version of libuv, which is used by the thread-loader package (which is also mentioned in your stack trace).

[You can add an environment variable as a workaround:](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/thread-loader/issues/191#issuecomment-1728002022)

> UV_USE_IO_URING=0